# How can I download archive of ubuntu community documentation so that i can use it offline?

Tags: documentation, archive, offline

How can I download archive of ubuntu community documentation so that i can use it offline?

Comment: I would just use some wget magic to grab the whole site pages and a program to print the pdf out of that. Or programmatically create a stack of that pages.

Comment: I might be wrong, but I am guessing that Akshar is relatively new to Linux, hence his desire to download documentation. Is it possible you can provide some "how to" details in your answer. If my assumption is wrong I apologize?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `wget -r -l 0 -np  -e robots=off -U "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT x.y; rv:10.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/10.0" -k -p -R *action=* https://help.ubuntu.com/community` in your target directory. @asutosh 's would hypothetically work, but one would incur robots.txt issues, extra pages downloaded, etc. I have tested this and it will download all HTML. If you want to get images, you may need to do a bit of tweaking.

Comment: Open up terminal by searching it in the launcher, then type(or paste) the command. You need to use rt-click, then paste option in terminal, as terminal does not recognize `ctrl+v` as paste.

Answer (score 2):

One simple way of doing this is when you are on your chosen a page in the community documentation website just select **Print**, then **Print to File** and save it as a **PDF** in your home folder

Comment: @Akshar  wants to get all of the pages in the help, not just one.

Comment: Agreed, but look at the title of the question. Both our answers will be helpful to members wishing to do this in the future. Whether they need one document or all. Having options is a good thing.

Comment: I do apologize for my ignorance.

Answer (score 1):

Just use wget `wget -p --convert-links -r website.com -o logfile` to download the whole site and convert the links to have it for offline viewing. Then you can view it offline in html format.
You can then convert it afterwards individually to pdfs or whatever suits you, as it is a hasstle to convert it instantly online while doing.

Comment: This is missing some parameters that would avoid incurring robots.txt issues, extra pages downloaded, etc.

Comment: I dont take the robot.txt into the account. Sorry for that. Only thing that matters most are the webpage we want to download.Extra stuff would be deleted later. Does the above command download the stuff you needed irrespective of extra stuffs? If so please that an answer

Comment: the command I gave just downloads the pages necessary, and not pages used for editing, login, page discussion, etc, etc. Your command downloads all of the pages linked, including redundant  edit pages.