# How can I browse Ubuntu Wiki offline?

Tags: browser, documentation, offline, ubuntu-wiki

I am accustomed to offline wiki browsing. I thought it would be great if I can read Ubuntu wiki in the same way.

Is there anyway I can read Ubuntu Wiki offline? Help will be much appreciated if I can download Wiki dumps to my computer much like in the case of Wikipedia.

I already tried suggestions given in this question [How can I download archive of ubuntu community documentation so that i can use it offline?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/129583/how-can-i-download-archive-of-ubuntu-community-documentation-so-that-i-can-use-i), but using the

```
wget -p --convert-links -r https://wiki.ubuntu.com -o logfile
```

gives me HTML files that are a real pain to browse when offline.

Please suggest me some other way to do this.

Comment: +1 because I also need wikis offline. I don't have permanent internet connection.....

Comment: @Ravi: I guess you might already know - but we can use webhttrack for doing this.

But I don't want to crawl through the site and put unnecessary load on the server. If only I can do something smarter, I prefer that!

Answer (score 0):

I searched around a bit and wasn't able to find anything similar to [Mediawiki's Dump](http://dumps.wikimedia.org/)
You may want to try using [`webchecker.py`](http://svn.python.org/view/python/trunk/Tools/webchecker/)

Answer (score 0):

From the second answer from [How can I download archive of ubuntu community documentation so that i can use it offline?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/129583/how-can-i-download-archive-of-ubuntu-community-documentation-so-that-i-can-use-i)

One simple way of doing this is when you are on your chosen a page in the community documentation website just select **Print**, then **Print to File** and save it as a **PDF** in your home folder

Answer (score 0):

## How to Browse Ubuntu-Wiki Offline

### 1. Save current page

In case you only need to save the current page simply use the **save page as** function in your browser.

Another way is to use the **pocket** function of your browser. Look at your browser manual or search for an extension.

### 2. wget

Using wget is another option

```
wget --recursive --no-clobber --page-requisites 7--html-extension \
     --convert-links --restrict-file-names=windows --domains website.org \
     --no-parent \
     www.yourwebsite.to.save
```

### 3. WebHTTrack Website Copier

**Description**: Copy websites to your computer, httrack with a Web interface
 WebHTTrack is an offline browser utility, allowing you to download a World
 Wide website from the Internet to a local directory, building recursively
 all directories, getting html, images, and other files from the server to
 your computer, using a step-by-step web interface.

Install it with

```
sudo apt-get install webhttrack
```

A good description of the functionality can be found on this [link](http://www.linux-magazine.com/Online/Features/WebHTTrack-Website-Copier).